# How to efficiently monitor text editors (or other processes) only if they are focused in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++

In Windows OS using VC++, I'm trying to write a monitor process that it will be enabled only when a window of a text editor (e.g. support both notepad and office word) is focused.

My first question is how I can get the window handler HWND of the focused window and also how to determine if this is a qualified window.

My second question is that is there any better way to detect if a qualified window is focused and/or loses focuse other than keep a while loop?

Thanks

Comment: So, you're writing a separate process to watch a text editor.  And, you want to know when the text editor window receives the focus.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. I need both when the text editor window receives the focus and loses the focus and also check the focused window when my process is up. And I need a way to check if the focused window is a window of a text editor.

Comment: Have you looked into setting a [Window Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) to trap the focus messages?